# Telerik WPF virtual grid - Array dimensions exceeded supported range error (VirtualQueryableCollectionView)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, telerik

I'm using Telerik UI for WPF and I created virtual grid using VirtualQueryableCollectionView. Virtual grid is doing fine until number of rows is big, I tried to show 200 million records and get following error:

Array dimensions exceeded supported range.
stack trace
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.set_Capacity(Int32 value) at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.EnsureCapacity(Int32 min)
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Insert(Int32 index, T item) at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.InsertItem(Int32 index, T item)
at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.System.Collections.IList.Add(Object value)
at Telerik.Windows.Data.VirtualQueryableCollectionView.b__9()
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

Can somebody help me?
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the "Progress Telerik UI for WPF" available in the Windows Store. There are a few examples on how to handle the VirtualGrid. The Example "Scrolling 1 Trillion Cells" e.g. contains the following code:

Example.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Telerik.Windows.Examples.VirtualGrid.Performance.Example"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"      
        xmlns:telerikQuickStart="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls.QuickStart;assembly=QuickStart.Common"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">   
    <Grid>
        <telerik:RadVirtualGrid x:Name="VirtualGrid"
                                ColumnWidth="90"
                                InitialRowCount="1000000"
                                InitialColumnCount="1000000"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Example.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
using Telerik.Windows.Controls.VirtualGrid;

namespace Telerik.Windows.Examples.VirtualGrid.Performance
{
    public partial class Example : UserControl
    {
        public Example()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.VirtualGrid.CellValueNeeded += this.OnCellValueNeeded;
            this.VirtualGrid.HeaderValueNeeded += this.OnHeaderValueNeeded;
        }

        private void OnHeaderValueNeeded(object sender, HeaderValueEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.HeaderOrientation == VirtualGridOrientation.Horizontal)
            {
                e.Value = string.Format("Column {0}", e.Index);
            }
        }

        private void OnCellValueNeeded(object sender, Controls.VirtualGrid.CellValueEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Value = string.Format("{0} {1}", e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe you can use this to play around. On a side note: Who wants to scroll through 200 million records? Is this usefull to anybody? This looks like a design flaw. You should probably overthink what you´re trying to achieve and find a better solution - e.g. paging. As far a I can recall the VirtualGrid requires all data to be loaded and just speeds up the time taken to display large amounts of data by virtualizing it. Do you really want to load 200 million records?